# Mac OSX 10.7 Lion AUPinkNoise does not compile

Tags: macos, osx-lion, core-audio, audiounit

Apple Technical Note TN2276 lists changes to audio unit code for Lion. I successfully applied the changes to FilterDemo sample and it compiles ok. Then I apple same changes to AUPinkNoise sample, but I get a linker error says undefined symbol _FilterFactory. I changed code in AUPinkNoise.cpp from 
    COMPONENT_ENTRY(AUPinkNoise)
to
    AUDIOCOMPONENT_ENTRY(AUBaseFactory, AUPinkNoise)

But that does not help. Being new to core audio I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, except with another audio unit project. From your description of the error, I think you forgot to edit the .exp file. In the .exp file you should have _"name"Entry and _"name"Factory. For example, in your case in the .exp file (located in the AUSource folder) it should be as follows

```
1:_AUPinkNoiseEntry
2:_AUPinkNoiseFactory
3:
```

Remember to have a blank line at the very end.

Also, you will want to edit the info.plist file as well by adding an AudioComponents Array entry and add AUPluginDispatch.cpp/h (located in the AUBase folder).

Comment: Indeed, my .exp file had wrong name for _AUPinkNoiseFactory. That solved the problem.